# Как найти Max для INT UNSIGNED в MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, max

Как найти "SELECT MAX(`Поле типа INT UNSIGNED`) FROM" для поля типа INT UNSIGNED в MySQL? Получаю ошибку "4294967295 is not a valid value for field 'MAX(`ID`)'. The allowed range is 0 to 2147483647". Потому-что в поле ID есть число 4294967295, а MAX поддерживает только 2147483647. Как найти максимальное число в этом случае?

Comment: Интересно в какой это версии mysql. У меня и на sqlfiddle max отлично работает с unsigned. Пример: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b611b5/1

Comment: Версия MySQL 5.7.17

Comment: Очень странно. Видите, тот пример на fiddle на 5.6 и там все ok. вряд ли они что то испортили за это время. у вас вот тот тест который я привел то же дает некорректный результат ?

Comment: И что интересно даст `max(cast(id as unsigned))` в доке написано, что он вообще приводит тип к bigint